# Move a commit from the end of a chain of changs to the beginning, in a new branch

Tags: git

I have a codebase with a commit that I'll call `first`. Six months of changes after `first` is a commit called `last`, and the very next commit I'll call `fix`. So we have:

```
first --------------------> last -> fix
```

I would like to split a new branch off of first:

```
first --------------------> last -> fix
   \->
```

and apply just `fix`:

```
first --------------------> last -> fix
   \-> fix
```

and *then* the other changes:

```
first --------------------> last -> fix
   \-> fix --------------------> last
```

I have tried various approaches involving merge, cherry-pick, and rebase, but in every case I get some kind of merge conflict. What baffles me is that the `fix` commit only changes one file, call it `a.txt`. However, the merge conflicts are in files other than `a.txt`. I don't even understand how this is possible. The commits between `first` and `last` clearly "make sense" (don't conflict) when replayed on top of first as they exist in the original branch. All I'm doing is tweaking `a.txt` and then trying to replay those same changes. How can I possibly get a conflict in anything other than `a.txt`?

Obviously it's hard to provide more context since this is a huge codebase with dozens of commits, and I can't really tell what's causing the issue - when I try to reproduce this in a baby git project I don't get merge conflicts.

---

Here one of the things I tried. All of `first`, `last` and `fix` are tags, if it's relevant.

```
git checkout first
git cherry-pick fix
git checkout -b new
git cherry-pick first..last
```

And then I get merge conflicts.

Comment: By "and _then_ the other changes" do you mean you want _all_ of `first..last` on the new branch? Or just `first -> fix -> last` ?

Comment: All of first..last. Basically, the tip of the new branch should contain the same code as the tip of the old branch, but the changes happened in a different order, if you see what I mean.

Comment: At what point do you get the merge conflicts? At `first -> fix`, or somewhere along the line of `fix ----> last`?

Comment: @9769953 I added an example to the end of the post

Comment: So merge conflicts originate when running `git cherry-pick first..last`?

Comment: @9769953 Exactly

Comment: Aren't you in detached HEAD after the first checkout anyway? It looks like an awkward way to do it

Comment: I wonder if it's better to first checkout a new branch before cherry-picking the fix. (edit: that seems to align with the above comment.)

Comment: Just to double check: there is no renaming, moving or creating of files (in particular, of course, `a.txt`) in the commits between (and including) first and last?

Comment: @9769953 I'm not sure, but the point is that the merge conflicts are in other, unrelated files. If I got a merge conflict for `a.txt` I'd understand

Comment: Are there any merge commits between first and last? If yes, and if any of them resolved conflicts during the merge, then you will absolutely have those same conflicts again.

Comment: @TTT Okay, but I just want to think about the range between first and last as a series of changes, and replay those changes. I don't really care if those changes were made by a guy typing into an editor, or by someone merging a different branch. I guess I'd like to just resolve the merges in the same way they were resolved the first time around? Can I do that?

Comment: *Can I do that?* Not in a fully automated way. You can use `git rebase --rebase-merges` (when you go with @timbiegeleisen's answer), but you still have to resolve the merge commits manually. But you can just copy over the state from the original merge commits except for `a.txt`, of course, because you do not want to undo the fix in the merge commit accidentally. You can use `git range-diff first@{1}..last@{1} first..last` to double-check that all went well: it should turn up pretty much empty. Also, the states before and after the operation must be identical.

Answer (score 0):

So you're taking an existing chain

```
first -> ... -> last -> fix  <HEAD
```

and rewriting it to

```
first -> fix -> ... -> last  <HEAD
```

just on a new branch (leaving the old one unchanged, and `first` is the common ancestor).

The obvious solution is just

```
$ git checkout -b newbranch fix
$ git rebase -i first
```

and rewrite the commit list

```
pick aaaaaaa commit after first
       ...
pick bbbbbbb last
pick ccccccc fix
```

to look like

```
pick ccccccc fix
pick aaaaaaa commit after first
       ...
pick bbbbbbb last
```

Comment: I also tried this - I also get merge conflicts, as soon as I save and close the editor to try and get the rebase to go through.

Comment: so you did _exactly_ that and you get merge conflicts that aren't anything to do with the changes in `fix`?

Answer (score 0):

We can break down your requirements into two steps.  First, do a cherry pick to bring in the `fix` commit in a new branch:

```
# from current branch
git switch -c feature
git cherry-pick fix
```

Then, do a git rebase onto to replay the desired sequence of commits after `first`, but *excluding* the final `fix` commit (it already having been cherry picked):

```
# from feature
git rebase --onto fix first last
```

Note: The `fix` commit above should use the *new* SHA-1 hash of the cherry picked commit.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand you correctly. I checkout `first` and make a new branch `feature`. Then I `cherry-pick fix`. I now get the SHA of the current commit, let's call that `sha`, and I go `rebase --onto $sha first last`. When I do that, I get merge errors during the rebase.

Comment: Correct, but they are not merge "errors," but rather merge conflicts.  And there may be no avoiding them.

Comment: But... how is that possible? How can I conceivably get conflicts in this situation? Like I said, `fix` only changes one file, and the conflicts are not for that file.

Comment: Rewriting history can always cause conflicts.

Comment: My mental model of how git works must be completely off, because that seems impossible to me. Would you be able to describe a minimal working example to reproduce this behavior (a merge conflict in an unrelated file when doing this kind of commit-reordering)?